# How do I data bind to a generic list in ASP.NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to bind my ListView control to a generic list of objects?

I thought I could code:

> listView1.DataSource =
>   fCol.ToList;
>   listView1.DataBind();

I get a cannot convert to object error.

I'm sure in Windows programming you use the BindingSource object.  Is there a web forms equivalent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the parentheses from the end of your ToList() call.

Comment: Ahhh... Can't believe I missed that!  I'm blaming on on the long weekend. :)

Comment: Still had to set up the LayoutTemplate and the ItemTemplate as well.  Not a having a good day!